# pause between frames and characters

Tags: c#, serial-port, modbus

I'm writing a C# application to communicate with external device via serial ports using the Modbus(RTU) protocol. To manage the serial port communication I'm using the SerialPort class. Modbus requires <1.5T delay between characters in one frame and >3.5T silence between frames (T is transmission time of 1 character (byte?)).

1. how to make sure there's no too long silence between bytes in frame I'm sending?
2. how to recognize there's >3.5T silence between bytes I receive?

Comment: (1) Always send the complete message in one `read()`syscall.  (2) Some USARTs have a "receiver timer" that is reset as each character is received.  If this timeout is set to something like 4T, then this timer will trigger an interrupt for "end of received message" when the Rx line is idle for that duration.  Do not bother trying to "measure" the arrival times between characters; that is a broken algorithm.  Note that "frame" is used to describe the "character" unit of UART/USARTs.

Comment: Rather than re-inventing the wheel, I would recommend you consider an existing modbus library, such as [nmodbus](https://code.google.com/p/nmodbus/).

Answer (score 4):

I have done something like this before. First, I do not believe you need to worry about the <1.5T delay between characters on transmit. When you do a send off a whole buffer the characters are transmitted without any pauses, specially on short messages.

The >3.5T silence between bytes to indicate an end-of-message on receive was originally designed in the 80s, where there was 1 interrupt per character received. It made sense at the time, but nowadays, with 16 byte FIFOs, USB adapters etc. between the incoming characters and your software, this just won't work.

So rather, examine your incoming message as often as is appropriate. Determine the message type, and then the length from the Modbus RTU message. Once you have the length, check how many characters you have received, and if you have enough, you are obviously done, else wait for more. Put in a timeout in case character(s) get lost.